# Check if a Realmobject is null in RN

Tags: react-native, realm

I am wondering if there is a way to check if a RealmObject is null or empty in React-native.

I need to check this because if it is not null I have to work and print the data, otherwise I need to skip the data printing.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Mark, at the moment i have am trying to solve the same issue and it still worked with the option "optional: true". I just got stucked and have some other issues. Maybe the following question with its code can help you a bit:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631219/realm-value-not-convertible-to-a-number

Comment: You should be able to use something like `anObj instanceof Realm.Object && anObj.isValid()`

Comment: @Tayschrenn thank you, I will try your hint!